# ¿Como crear columnas dinámicamente con datatables.js?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Utilizo el plugin datatables.js para mostrar datos en un proyecto, actualmente lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        table= $('#Providers-table').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            ordering: true,
            scroller: {
                loadingIndicator: true
            },
            ajax: {
                url: getDataUrl,
                dataSrc: ""
            },
            columns: [
                { data: "C_prove" },
                { data: "Descripcion" },
                { data: "Rfc_proveedor" },
                { data: "Nombre_comprador" },
                {
                    render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        return "<label><input type='checkbox' class='providerCheckbox' name='providerCheckbox' providerID='" + full.C_prove + "' checked /><span></span></label>"
                    }
                },
            ]
        });
    });
```

la instrucción funciona bien, pero deseo agregar x columnas más, basados en un número. El número lo obtengo mediante una consulta a mi base de datos. por ejemplo, si el número es un 2, quisiera que en el apartado `columns` quede algo así:

```
columns: [
                    { data: "C_prove" },
                    { data: "Descripcion" },
                    { data: "Rfc_proveedor" },
                    { data: "Nombre_comprador" },
                    {
                        render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                            return "<label><input type='checkbox' class='providerCheckbox' name='providerCheckbox' providerID='" + full.C_prove + "' checked /><span></span></label>"
                        }
                    },
                    //aquí entran los campos extras
                    {data: "campoextra1"},
                    {data: "campoextra2"}
                ]
```

he encontrado algunos ejemplos pero no los he entendido del todo, no me queda claro como es que lo hacen. si de algo sirve, dejaré un enlace de referencia aquí debajo:

[Referencia](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/33886/dynamic-columns-from-ajax-data-source)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes usar 3 parametros:

columns
columnsDef
data

Los 3 parametros admiten objetos, por lo que puedes declararlos, asignarlos y cambiar valores cuando quieras.

Declaracion Inicial:

```
var datos = [
            { "Codigo": 43447, "Tipo": "sin-imagen.jpg", "precio": "APORT" },
            { "Codigo": 43447, "Tipo": "sin-imagen.jpg", "precio": "APORT" }
        ]

        var titulos = [
            { "title": "uno", "targets": 0 },

            { "title": "dos", "targets": 1 },
            { "title": "tres", "targets": 2 }
        ];

        var columnas = [
            { "data": "Codigo" },
            { "data": "Tipo" },
            { "data": "precio" },
        ];
```

Ahora Creas el datatable

```
var tablaDatos = $('#tablaProductos').DataTable({
                "pageLength": "25",
                "responsive": true,
                "columns": columnas,
                "columnDefs": titulos,
                "data": datos1
            });
```

Si necesitas asignar, destruyes el datatable con

```
tablaDatos.destroy();
```

Y vuelves a establecerla con

```
tablaDatos = $('#tablaProductos').DataTable({
                "pageLength": "25",
                "responsive": true,
                "columns": columnas,
                "columnDefs": titulos,
                "data": datos1
            });
```

Cada vez que quieras editar columnas, destruye la tabla y pintala de nuevo, asi evitas problemas